# Get localized currency display name from CLDR in PHP

Tags: php, unicode, icu, cldr

I need to output localized currency names on a webpage.

USD | ameriški dolar

EUR | euro

I can't seem to find a way to do it through the intl library, although the data is present in Unicode CLDR.

E.g. Slovenian http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/tags/latest/common/main/sl.xml

Is there any way to use this data, aside from parsing and locally storing data from the remote CLDR XML files for each display language I have?

Comment: You might need a library like https://github.com/commerceguys/intl

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Cool find, I believe this is the only way so please post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need a library like [commerceguys/intl](https://github.com/commerceguys/intl), which has a `getName()` method.